# comparing contents of 2 lists of lists

Tags: python, list

Here's the task I am having trouble with:

Given 2 lists of lists, filter them down to only items that have nothing in common. E. g. if inner lists are identical, filter them out. If inner lists have at least one item in common, also filter them out.

Note: There is only one level of nesting. The inner lists consist only of strings. I have a solution that works, but it's EXTREMELY messy. Looking for feedback to improve:

First I filter out the exact matches in both lists:

```
l3 = filter(lambda x: x not in l2, l1)
l4 = filter(lambda x: x not in l1, l2)
```

I end up with 2 lists of lists that do not have exactly the same items. Now I want to iterate over the inner lists, and get rid of any of them that share items with any of the inner lists of the other.

I am doing:

```
    for i in l3:
        for j in i:
            for k in l4:
                if j in k:
                    print j, k
                    removel3.append(tuple(i))
                    removel4.append(tuple(k))
    for i in l4:
        for j in i:
            for k in l3:
                if j in k:
                    removel3.append(tuple(k))
                    removel4.append(tuple(i))
    for i in list(set(removel3)):
        l3.remove(list(i))
    for i in list(set(removel4)):
        l4.remove(list(i))
```

(building separate lists of things to remove from lists because removing directly in the iterating loop messes up list indexing and skips items. There has to be a better way of doing it, but I don't know of it.)

But yeah. It gets the job done, but going from tuples to sets to lists to more tuples... sounds very nonpythonic. :) Would be happy to see any feedback!

EDIT:

Sample input:

```
l1 = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H']]
l2 = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'I'], ['K', 'L', 'M']]
```

After all the transformations above, end up with:

```
>>> l3
[['F', 'G', 'H']]
>>> l4
[['K', 'L', 'M']]
```

Comment: Can you give a sample input & expected output?

Comment: Show us some data: sample input and desired output.

Comment: @FMc: great minds think alike

Comment: There you go, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a filter like this is what you want

```
filter(lambda sublist:not any(set(sublist).intersection(x) for x in list2),list1)
```

Comment: This only returns for the first list. Maybe you meant to do this twice?

Comment: Yeah, there'd have to be one with l2, l1, and another with l1, l2. But it does get the job done. I haven't had much experience with .intersection(), need to look into that. Thanks so much!

Comment: This would be more pythonic and more efficient as a list comprehension: `[sublist for sublist in list1 if not any(set(sublist).intersection(x) for x in list2]`

Comment: FWIW, this creates lots of sets over an over again.  you'd be better off doing `set2 = map(set, list2)` ahead of time and then using `set2` in the `any` generator rather than `list2`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that I understand you, but I'm gonna give it a shot.

```
# first, get all elements from each list as a flat set.
import itertools
set1 = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list1))
set2 = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2))

#Now, figure out which elements they have in common
common_elements = set1 & set2

#Now eliminate inner lists which have elements in the common set
new_list1 = [lst for lst in list1 if not any(x in common_elements for x in lst)]
new_list2 = [lst for lst in list2 if not any(x in common_elements for x in lst)]
```

Note that I can do this because the sublists hold hashable objects.

Comment: what about `if not set(lst).intersection(common_elements)` ? but yeah probably more efficient than my solution ... but i think they both work :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- `if not common_elements.intersection(lst)` would be more efficient and I thought of using that.  Using `any` allows for short circuiting so it's a little better algorithmically.  When the rubber meets the road, we'd need to do real tests with real data to see which is actually faster -- the implementation of `set.intersection` might beat out the short circuiting advantages of `any`.

Comment: This works as well, but Joran's answer seems better, at least aesthetically :) Thank you!